# How to use powershell import contacts for users on exchange 2013?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

We have exchange 2013 and users are using OWA to access it. There is no function that users can import contacts themselves from a file in OWA. Is there a way that I can import contacts for users on the server side by powershell?

1. I need to export all contacts from any user lets say user "A" into a csv file.
2. Then I need to import this csv file for user "B"

When I try `get-mailcontact -id "user" | format-list` i got error messages saying that "user" can't be found on domain.....but this user is an active domain user.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, follow the steps as seen in this blog post.  You'll need to enable Exchange Web Services impersonation for your users first, and then you can mass import contacts for your individual users.

http://www.stevieg.org/2010/07/using-powershell-to-import-contacts-into-exchange-and-outlook-live/

Once you've enable Exchange Web Services impersonation, it is very easy to import contacts, here's the syntax you'll use.

```
.\Import-MailboxContacts.ps1 -CSVFileName .\Contacts.csv `
-EmailAddress userToGetContacts@yourdomain.com -EwsUrl https://server/EWS/Exchange.asmx
```

Comment: yeah I saw this too. the reason that I dont want to try this is I CAN NOT do it right away on the production exchange server....